# My fetch request just isn't executing, and I am not sure why

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch-api, express-jwt

So I am using react for my front-end and I am trying to run this fetch request to my node js backend to retrieve some data but the fetch just won't execute inside my useEffect.

I am fairly new to programming but I am very confused as similar code is running perfectly fine elsewhere in my application. The first part of the function will run and execution will just stop at the fetch request. Any idea why?

I have tried to alter my request many times but the same issue still persists.

Here is my code

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getPosts = async () => {
      try {
        const token = AuthContext.loggedIn() ? AuthContext.getToken() : 0;

        console.log(token);

        if (!token) {
          return false;
        }

        const response = await fetch(
          "http://localhost:5008/workout/getAllPosts",
          {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          }
        );

        console.log(response);

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Something went wrong");
        }

        const { result } = await response.json();

        setPosts(result);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    };

    getPosts();
  }, []);
```

Comment: When you debug, what specifically happens?  Are there any errors on the browser's development console?  Is the `token` logged to the console?  Does it have a "truthy" value?  Is the AJAX request being made afterward?  "just isn't executing" doesn't really tell us anything about the problem.

Comment: Open the network tab in Developer tools and see if it makes an xhr request.

Comment: I have checked my dev tools and no such request is being made.

Answer (score 0):

Handling error with fetch api is a bit tricky, you might need to debug it properly to get something useful. By default errors are returned only when its a network issue

You can try this

fetcher.js <= I have a file to handle api calls

```
const fetcher = (url, options) =>
  fetch(url, options)
    .then(async (response) => {
      if (!response.ok) throw await response.json();
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") console.log(err);
      throw err;
    });
```

Now in your code, you can do this:

```
await fetcher({
  url: "http://localhost:5008/workout/getAllPosts",
  options: {
             method: "GET",
             headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, },
           }
}).then((res)=>console.log(res))
  .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
```